# fprintf size limitation

Tags: matlab, text, printf

When using fprintf in matlab, I have run into a problem. I am writing a large character array like so:

```
fileID = fopen(s,'w');                                  
fprintf(fileID,'%s',test_text);                             
fclose(fileID);
```

When outputting a text file anything smaller than 1GB it seems to work, however going past that will cause the output file to be empty (0 bytes). I believe this maybe a 32-bit limitation. Is this correct, and if so is there any workaround?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. This script writes 2GB of textdata to test.txt and runs without error. I use matlab 2017a on windows 7 64-bit. (does take 43 seconds)

```
st = char(randi([0 255],[1,2^31],'uint8')); %2GB of textdata
fileID = fopen('test.txt','w');                                  
fprintf(fileID,'%s',st);                             
fclose(fileID);
```

What surprised me was that matlab uses 2 bytes per char value.

Comment: Hmm I just ran your exact code and it did what I described and instantly outputted a 0 byte empty file. I am using Windows 7 64-bit and Matlab R2016b. I will try updating to the latest 2017a and try again....

Comment: `char` data types in most modern languages are 2 bytes in order to support Unicode.